# FullCalendar customize week display

Tags: fullcalendar

Now my callendar week is like this:  `Friday dd/mm`. I'd like to know if there is a way to hide the day/month number and only shows the name of the day.

Couldn't find anything [Here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/)

My code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Page is now ready, initialize calenda.

        $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                center: 'title',
                left: '',
                right: ''
            },          
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',          



            firstDay: 1,
            weekends: false,

            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Event1',
                    start: '2016-03-14',
                    end:'2016-03-14T04:00'            
                }
            ],

        })
    });
</script>
```

And this is what I'd like to change

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the week view columnFormat

Paste the code below under the line  where you set the default view "        defaultView: 'agendaWeek', "

```
   views: {
        week: {
            columnFormat: 'ddd'
        }
    },
```

[image]

The ddd shows Sat, Sun etc if you change it to dddd it will show Saturday , Sunday etc.

But of course you can set it to what ever you like it to show.